# Bind value of html element to ng-model dynamicall angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an html element (`div`)
I append anther html element like (`textarea`) to to this (`div`), I want to bind the value of the added element to `ng-model` which is an area

.html file

```
<div id="new-view{{$index}}"></div>
```

.js file

```
var parent = $('#new-view' + controllerIndex); 

var question = angular.element('<textarea data-ng-model="self.array['+Index+'].question"></textarea>');

parent.append(question);
```

How to I bind what the user will write inside this text area to the array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background to make it short.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another approach with ng-repeat directive. Operate on your data. And angular 2-way binding will update your interface.

Little example: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/hb7lu/

```
<div >
    <textarea ng-repeat="q in questions" ng-model="q.text"></textarea>        
</div>
```